# DropDownList From Objects MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select, viewbag

Ok so I want make a `DropDownList` from my object list
here is my getting object method

```
public List<Category> GetCategoriesList()
{
    BaseShopEntities context = new BaseShopEntities();
    List<Category> uniqCategories = (from c in context.Category
                                             select c).Distinct().ToList<Category>();

    return uniqCategories;
}
```

I was trying to put it into the `ViewBag` like this:

```
ViewBag.Categories = proxy.GetCategoriesList().ToList();
```

If im taking only names of Categorys and parsing it to string there is no problem but I need ID too

I Want get data like this but don't know how

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories.Name));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, `GetCategoriesList` already returns a List, so you don't need `ToList` when you add it to the ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.Categories = proxy.GetCategoriesList();
```

Secondly, in order to create a DropDownList that has independent names and values, you need the following overload of the `SelectList` constructor:

```
SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String)
```

Here, you specify the list with which to populate the `SelectList` as well as two strings, where the first is the name of the *value* field of the elements in the list and the second is the name of the *text* field. The values of these fields are then retrieved using reflection. In your case, it'll probably look something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID",
    new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories, "Id", "Name"));
```

Here, I am assuming that each category has an `Id` field and a `Name` field. If these field names aren't correct, you'll need to change the strings passed into the `SelectList` constructor accordingly.

On a side note: You should create a separate view model for categories that is separate from your database entity class and create a list of these instead. Your views shouldn't be accessing your data entities directly.

Comment: Saved my hours. Worked like a charm